# Assigning values to a column based on relative magnitudes of other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Please consider the series:

```
series = pd.Series(np.random.normal(0, 1, 100))
```

Here's a moving average df that contains moving averages of this series, with each column corresponding to moving averages using one value in `window = [2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]`

```
ma_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in window:
    ma_df['ma'+ str(i)] = series.rolling(window = i).mean()

df = pd.concat([ma_df, series], axis =1)

df.tail()
     ma2   ma5  ma10  ma15  ma20  ma25  series
95 -0.66 -0.15  0.15 -0.02 -0.09 -0.16    0.11
96  0.28 -0.09  0.11  0.02 -0.05 -0.14    0.46
97  0.76 -0.09  0.28  0.08 -0.04 -0.07    1.06
98  1.10  0.27  0.32  0.19  0.02 -0.01    1.13
99  1.03  0.74  0.39  0.32  0.13  0.01    0.94
```

**Question:** I wish to create a column `df['relative_positions']` which takes different values depending on the relative magnitude of different columns of df. For example,`df['positions']`=0 if the following conditions are met:

```
df['relative_positions'] [(df.series > df.ma5) & (df.series > df.ma10) & (df.series < df.ma15) & (df.series > df.ma25) & (df.ma10 > df.ma25) & ....] = 0
```

or `df['positions']`= 1 if:

```
df['relative_positions'] [(df.series < df.ma5) & (df.series< df.ma10) & (df.ma25 < df.ma15) & (df.ma10 < df.ma25) & (df.series < df.ma25) & ....] = 1
```

or `df['positions']`= 2 if:

```
df['relative_positions'] [(df.ma20 < df.ma5) & (df.series > df.ma20) & (df.ma20 < df.ma15) & (df.ma25 < df.series) & (df.series < df.ma5) & ....] = 2
```

***and so on so forth.*** In each set of conditions, all columns must be compared to all other columns, with both `<` and `>` signs.
In short, `df['relative_positions']` takes different values (don't matter what) depending on the magnitude of the columns relative to one another (larger or smaller).

**Issue:**
As you can see, writing these conditions by hand is close to impossible. Is there any way I can automatically populate such lists of permutations of conditions?

I'm sorry if the question is vague. Will be happy to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons are yielding nothing, because `df.series` is always higher than the rolling means in the corresponding columns. Nevertheless, you might need `np.where` to do your comparisons as:

```
df['relative_positions'] = np.where((df.series > df.ma5) & (df.series > df.ma10) & (**df.series > df.ma15**) & (df.series > df.ma25) & (df.ma10 > df.ma25), 0, 
                                   np.where((df.series < df.ma5) & (df.series< df.ma10) & (df.ma25 < df.ma15) & (df.ma10 < df.ma25) & (df.series < df.ma25), 1, np.where((df.ma20 < df.ma5) & (df.series > df.ma20) & (df.ma20 < df.ma15) & (df.ma25 < df.series) & (df.series < df.ma5), 2, 'empty')))
```

For testing purposes I changed `(**df.series > df.ma15**)` to larger instead of lower. Otherwise you get empty's only.

```
df.tail()

     ma2   ma5  ma10  ma15  ma20  ma25  series relative_positions
95  94.5  93.0  90.5  88.0  85.5  83.0      95                  0
96  95.5  94.0  91.5  89.0  86.5  84.0      96                  0
97  96.5  95.0  92.5  90.0  87.5  85.0      97                  0
98  97.5  96.0  93.5  91.0  88.5  86.0      98                  0
99  98.5  97.0  94.5  92.0  89.5  87.0      99                  0
```

Comment: I'm sorry it was my oversight in reproducing the issue. The reason the comparisons yielded nothing was that the series was all positive increasing numbers. Changing that to some normally-distributed numbers solves the issue. I edited the questions. Anyways, your answer does not address my question. My issue is not using `np.where` to find where in the data the conditions I typed work. My issue is populating an all-inclusive, permutation-like list of those conditions.

Comment: @Saeed then you need to provide an example of the desired result